# Chrome Web Inspector Dev Tools Changed - Revert to older style

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I've been using Chrome forever for development, but it seems as if the last few versions - they've changed the functionally of the Web Inspector.

For instance, before I was able to search the 'Resources' tab, but now I have to search via the console, which makes it less easier than the way before I think Chrome 31.

Is there a way to rever back to the previous Web Inspector?

Same thing with Safari, but they changed their Web Inspector long before...

Thanks,
Roc.

Comment: what's wrong with uninstalling chrome and install an older version that has the previous inspector that you prefer?

Comment: The updates Chrome made really. Though I may have to revert back, which sucks.

Comment: So you mean you want to keep the current/latest version while using the old inspector?

Comment: If you feel like the Resources panel search has regressed, please report it at http://crbug.com/new